# using dustjs-helpers contextDump with expressjs

Tags: node.js, dust.js

I am using dustjs as the templating engine in an express app, and was wondering if anyone has successfully used the contextDump helper in a server side template in express?  I followed the consolidate example for integrating dust with express, and it is working well. The helpers are there, as I'm able to do a simple test with the eq helper and it works. but when trying to dump the context I'm not seeing it anywhere. here is a sample template:

```
{>layout/}
{<content}
  <ul>
    {#users}
      <li>{username} - <a href="/users/{id}/tasks/create">Create New Task</a>
        <ul>
          {#user.tasks}
          <li>{title} - <a href="/users/{user.id}/tasks/{task.id}/destroy">Delete Task</a> |
            <a href="/users/{user.id}/tasks/{task.id}/update">Update Task</a></li>
          {/user.tasks}
        </ul>
      </li>
    {/users}
  </ul>
{/content}
{@contextDump to="console"/}
```

Here's my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var db = require ('./models');
var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');
var cons = require('consolidate');

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.set('models', db);

//configure dust
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('template_engine', 'dust');
app.engine('dust', cons.dust);

app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

//require routes
require('./routes')(app);
require('./routes/user')(app);
require('./routes/task')(app);


db
  .sequelize
  .sync({ force: true })
  .complete(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
        console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
      });
    }
  });
```

and here's package.json:

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.4.6",
    "sequelize": "~2.0.0-beta.5",
    "mysql": "~2.0.0-rc2",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "async": "~0.2.9",
    "dustjs-linkedin": "~2.2.2",
    "dustjs-helpers": "~1.1.1",
    "consolidate": "~0.10.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to get simple helpers to work and to write my own. Do you have an example on how to do the eq helper?